# IIS is terminating CGI process when client disconnect

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8

The following C snippet is supposed to be run by Windows IIS, as a CGI .exe program.
It outputs three character "a, b, c" with a 10 second delay between them.

However, if I use a browser to access the program, and then reloads the browser page to access the program again - then I get two processes running in parallell on the IIS.
At the browser I will of course only see the output of process 2, as the TCP connection to process 1 has been closed after the first "a" was received.

On the Windows server process 2 happily runs to completion, but processes 1 runs only until it outputs the second character "b".
The WriteFile that outputs that "b" is successful, and also the following log write "Done" is also excuted (thus, there is no fatil exception in WriteFile).
But then, suddenly, process 1 is terminated.

My theory is that IIS detects that some output is received from process 1, and that IIS then forcibly terminates it (as the client is disconnected)

If I add a 10ms sleep (commented below) after the WriteFile, then process 1 does not even execute the log write "Done".
I suppose that this is due to the fact that IIS needs a little time to perform that Terminate call, and without the Sleep the process has time to execute at least the log write "Done" before IIS terminates.

Does anybody recognize this?
And how do I stop IIS from terminating the process (except by beginning by forking it into a new process, that is not owned by IIS)
I really would like to run process 1 all the way to the end, even if no client is "listening" to it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
void out(char *text)
{
    int   i;
    int   written;
    char   buf[1000];
    FILE   *fp;

    for(i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
        buf[i] = (text[i] == '\n' ? '^' : text[i]);
    buf[i] = '\0';
    if((fp = fopen("/temp/testkill.txt", "a")) != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d: Write %s\n", _getpid(), buf);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    if(WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), text, strlen(text), &written, NULL) == 0)
        written = -1;
//  Sleep(10);

    if((fp = fopen("/temp/testkill.txt", "a")) != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d: Done! %s (%d)\n", _getpid(), buf, written);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
main()
{
    out("Content-Type: text/html\n\n<html><body>\n");
    out("a");
    Sleep(10000);
    out("b");
    Sleep(10000);
    out("c");
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use FastCGI,[FastCGI](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/fastcgi-for-iis) for IIS enables popular application frameworks that support the FastCGI protocol to be hosted on the IIS web server in a high-performance and reliable way

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to switch from CGI to anything else. The only solution that I can see right now, is to always spawn a new process with CreateProcess, waiting for the "child" to complete - and thus, the waiting process is the only one to be killed by IIS when the client disconnects.